# How to mark locations on google map by having array of ip addresses, not lat & lng coordinates

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to mark locations on google map using [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). 
How to do the same if I have a php/javascript array of ip addresses, not lat and lng coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some way to convert them from IP addresses to co-ordinates - to which there is a post on StackOverflow asking [this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663371/longitude-and-latitude-value-from-ip-address).

My favourite is [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/) which offers the service for free and can return you the information you require using a very simple GET request:

```
http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<your_api_key>&ip=74.125.45.100
```

If you replace `ip-country` with `ip-city` then you get city level precision.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ip-geolocation service that can convert the IP address into *approximate* geographical coordinates.  See something like http://ip2location.com/ which I believe offers a paid API service.  I don't know if there is any unlimited free service to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I like http://www.iptolatlng.com/ because it gives me staight JSON and it gives me the results I want in the easiest fashion.